# VBA is unable to create a connection to a remote SQL Database

Tags: vba

I've created an excel front end interface to connect with and manipulate an SQL database. I recently received a laptop, and would like to be able to manipulate the data from excel on said laptop. I established a connection using SQL Server Management Studios to the database. [image]

I've tried to update my excel file; however, the VBA code can not connect to the SQL database. I've changed a few of the variables around and set Integrated Security too, but nothing has worked so far. The error message readouts can be seen here: [image]

Here is the code related to the DB connection:

```
Dim cnSQL As ADODB.Connection
Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
cnSQL.Open "Provider = SQLOLEDB; Integrated Security = SSPI, Data Source = IP Address,Static TP Port; UID = username; PWD =pwd@; Initial Catalog = database"
```

The error message highlights the second line of code. I'm hoping to be able to connect to the DB from my laptop.

Comment: You are erroring on the `Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection` line?

Comment: @JNevill the error is in the cnSQL.Open line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a few days, I finally got this to work.  There are two important steps you need to take to make excel work with a Remote SQL network.  First here is the code used to connect:

```
Dim cnSQL As ADODB.Connection
Dim ServerName As String
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim userID As String
Dim password As String
ServerName = "IP Addresss,Port"
DatabaseName = "DB Name"
userID = "username"
password = "pwd"
Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
sqlCommand.ActiveConnection = cnSQL
```

After I changed the code to this, I got a new error: "optional feature not implemented."  To fix this error, I changed the data type of all 'adDate' to 'adDBTimeStamp.'  This works for some reason, I don't know why.  It works.